# Left Join not filtering results

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL. 
Below is my table structure.

batch_admissions

```
------------------------+
batchId | studentId     |
----------------------- +
1       |   1           |
1       |   2           |
1       |   3           |
2       |   1           |
2       |   2           |
------------------------+
```

attendance_master

```
----------------------------+
attendance  | studentId     |
----------------------------+
P           |   1           |
P           |   2           |
P           |   3           |
----------------------------+
```

desire result if `batchId=2` as below as attendance_master only contain record of `batchId=1`

```
----------------------------+
attendance  | studentId     |
----------------------------+
            |   1           |
            |   2           |
----------------------------+
```

But currently I am getting all record back from attendance_master irrespective of change in batchId. 
What wrong in my query? I think left join should do the job. but not working

```
SELECT 
            a.attendanceId, 
               a.attendanceDate, 
            a.attendance, 
            a.Remarks, 
            CONCAT(b.studentFirstName, ' ', COALESCE(b.studentMiddleName,'') , ' ', b.studentLastName) as studentName , 
            c.classRollNum,
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( a.attendanceDate , '-', 3 ),'-',-1) AS attDay, 
            CASE WHEN DAYNAME(a.attendanceDate) = 'Monday' THEN 'Mon' 
                    WHEN DAYNAME(a.attendanceDate) = 'Tuesday' THEN 'Tue' 
                    WHEN DAYNAME(a.attendanceDate) = 'Wednesday' THEN 'Wed' 
                    WHEN DAYNAME(a.attendanceDate) = 'Thursday' THEN 'Thu' 
                    WHEN DAYNAME(a.attendanceDate) = 'Friday' THEN 'Fri'
                    WHEN DAYNAME(a.attendanceDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 'Sat'
                    WHEN DAYNAME(a.attendanceDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 'Sun'
            END as attDayName
,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( a.attendanceDate , '-', 3 ),'-',-1),'.',c.classRollNum) as Idx
FROM attendance_master a 
LEFT JOIN student_master b ON a.studentId = b.studentId 
LEFT JOIN batch_admissions c ON c.studentId = a.studentId AND c.batchId=1 
 WHERE a.attendanceDate BETWEEN '2016-03-01' AND '2016-03-31' 
ORDER BY c.classRollNum ASC


-------------
```

Basically I trying to avoid triggering two queries and want result in single query.
`batch_admissions` table holds series of batch with N numbers student in it. 
`attendance_master` table holds attendance of students for all batch. 
On web page I am displaying table grid report, per batch wise. 
What I am trying to achieve,

`case 1` : when attendance_master NOT contain attendance for batchId for specific period. Still want list of student for that batch

```
-------------------------------------------------------
BatchId |studentId  |   Mon |   Tue |   Wed | Thus  |
------------------------------------------------------
1       |   11      |       |       |       |       |
1       |   12      |       |       |       |       |
..      |   ..      |       |       |       |       |
```

`Case 2`: when attendance_master contain attendance for batchId for specific period.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
BatchId |studentId  |   Mon |   Tue |   Wed | Thus  |
------------------------------------------------------
2       |   1       |   P   |   P   |   P   |   P   |
2       |   2       |   P   |   A   |   P   |   P   |
..      |   ..      |   P   |   P   |   P   |   P   |
```

Alternate I can trigger two queries to achieve this logically. One for get of student for batch, and then getting attendance detail for all those student.

Comment: @xQbert: No. I am expecting, if attendance_master not contain any data for batchId=2 students then I want all studentId for batchId=2 and rest of column should blank. I other word, irrespective data in  attendance_master .... want studentId base on batchId from batch_admissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok... so return all records from batch admissions and the related student_master data (which there will always be records) and the associated attendance master data...

```
FROM batch_admissions c 
INNER JOIN student_master b 
  ON a.studentId = c.studentId 
LEFT JOIN attendance_master a 
  ON c.studentId = a.studentId 
 and a.attendanceDate BETWEEN '2016-03-01' AND '2016-03-31'     
WHERE c.batchId=1 
ORDER BY c.classRollNum ASC
```

Comment: this will return no record if attendance_master not hold batchId=1 students. I want list of studentId in all condition and rest of col can be NULL.

Comment: ok updated based on your comment.  I think you are after all batch_admissions with batchID 1 and the guaranteed related student_master data, and any attendance_master data related to the student if it's in March.  The reason I'm struggling with this is you are asking for help on the query but I don't understand what you're after.  The query doesn't help because it's wrong.  So in plain english describe what you are after (or do I have it now)

Comment: Thanks for helping and spending time. I update the question above. Hoping I clear this time.

Comment: got it with nested query.